# Login to a new machine and run the rest of csh script in that new machine

Tags: linux, shell, csh

I have a linux csh code. I need to run part of the code in another virtual machine. How can I do that?

My code has following steps

1. echo $PWD
2. rsh
3. mkdir NEW
4. cd NEW
5. echo $PWD
6. Logout from new machine
7. cd <previous location
8. echo $PWD

Step 3-6 should be executed in new machine.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it like that w/ `rsh`.

```
echo $PWD
rsh <host> 'mkdir NEW; cd NEW; echo $PWD'
cd <previous location
echo $PWD
```

I haven't used `rsh` in decades, and none of the machines I have access to have the client or the server installed, so I can't say whether this will work or not for sure.

Comment: agreed about `rsh`. O.P. can replace `rsh` with `ssh` and above should worK **once the `ssh` keys are setup correctly** (can be a headache). Good luck to all.

Comment: @amareghn - pleased to hear that. Please feel free to "Accept" my answer. :)